# DotNetOpenAuth error in production server

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnetopenauth

I'm using the latest [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) version. In localhost everything works fine.

I see the following exception message:

> Unable to cast object of type 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform' to type 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.IRelyingPartyBehavior'

The stack trace is:

```
at DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.TypeConfigurationElement1.CreateInstance(T defaultValue, Boolean allowInternals)
at DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.TypeConfigurationCollection1.<>c__DisplayClass4.<CreateInstances>b__2(TypeConfigurationElement1 element)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator2.MoveNext()
at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty..ctor(ICryptoKeyStore cryptoKeyStore, INonceStore nonceStore)
at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty..ctor()
at Ideiota.WebApp.Modules.Login.HandleOpenIdProviderResponse()
at Ideiota.WebApp.Modules.Login.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But the error is in config file. The new version have changes...

Comment: edits to your question should be added to the original question. Not as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that encounters this, here's the problem as I experienced it. Upgrading to this new version (via NuGet in my case) added some new config, but didn't remove the old and invalid config.

In your `Web.config`:

```
<!-- old and invalid, remove this line -->
<add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth" />
<!-- keep this new line -->
<add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform,
           DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" />
```